# vue-CLI outputting very concerning error (security question)

Tags: vue.js, security, npm, vue-cli

I'm building an application with Vue.js.  Suddenly, vue-cli has begun outputting errors that have me concerned that perhaps one or more of my dependencies has something nefarious in it.

When I run npm run serve (vue-cli serve), the command **succeeds**, but outputs several lines of error messages like the following:

> (node:366423) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/initrd.img'

It also fails to stat `/home/jordan/.steampath`, `/initrd.img.old`, `/vmlinuz`, and `/vmlinuz.old`.

It also sometimes outputs these lines when hot-reloading.

I'm concerned because it seems there should be ZERO reason for it to even try to stat kernel files or my steampath.  It seems to be looking at things it shouldn't need to (but is apparently being prevented from doing so).

Should I be concerned about security?  Is this evidence that I'm using a vue or NPM plugin with nefarious code in it?  Or is this a simple misconfiguration somewhere?

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pp10-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.15.5",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.15.5",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.16.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "filepond": "^4.13.6",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "npm-cache": "^0.7.0",
    "pdfjs": "^2.3.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.3.200",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.10.2",
    "tinymce": "^5.3.0",
    "underscore": "^1.10.2",
    "v-calendar": "^1.0.8",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-color": "^2.7.1",
    "vue-filepond": "^5.1.3",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.35",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-phone-number-input": "^1.1.9",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-stepper-component": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-tour": "^1.3.1",
    "vue-worker": "^1.2.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Solution:**

1. Removed nodejs and npm, deleted all associated folders, and reinstalled nodejs and npm by using [nvm (node version manager)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).  I chose the current version of node (14 as of this writing).
2. Removed node_modules and package-lock.json within the project.
3. Ran npm install (in project folder)
4. Installed vue-cli globally: `npm install -g @vue/cli`
5. When builds failed, followed prompts to install missing dependencies.
6. FINALLY it worked.

Comment: _"Should I be concerned about security?"_ definitely. Have you run `npm audit` to see if there are any security issues in dependent packages?

Comment: @Phil -- I have.  However the issue started *after* updating, so I rolled back.

Comment: Can you share your`package.json` dependencies / devDependencies?

Comment: @Phil -- I've added the package.json to the question.

Comment: Try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, then re-run `npm install` and `npm audit`. What are the results of that? Does the problem still show if you run `npm run serve`?

Comment: @Phil I ended up blowing away node_modules, package-lock.json, deleting the global node_modules folder (and deleting the softlinks pointing there for npm, node, vue, etc), reinstalling node and npm via nvm, running npm install, resolving some missing dependencies, and FINALLY it quit giving that error.  Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Just got a similar error with initrd.img.old and vmlinuz.old. The only packages we share are sass and sass-loader. Running node 10.22.0 and npm 6.14.6

Comment: @AndrewOlney THAT is very interesting.  Thanks for the information.  I haven't seen the issue recur on my system, but if it does, I'm looking at sass.

Comment: Same issue with create-react-app and Razzle. Posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483296/concerning-build-errors-about-initrd-img-and-vmlinuz-in-a-fresh-create-rea

Comment: From what I can tell (based on monkey patching `fs.stat` and `fs.readdir`) this is webpack dev server watching the world. I've not gotten to the bottom of why, but it seems to be to do with it watching all the directories that got recursed into with paths that contain `../`. More investigation required, but debugging promise chains is really painful.

Answer (score 0):

facing the same issue with nuxt.js, audit does not mention anything regarding this. Howto find the npm module? String `steam` is not present, likely obfuscated as bytearray or else

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, [upgrading to node 12.18.3](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and running `npm rebuild node-sass` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the latest dependencies in your package.json (manually check on npmjs.com or your npm registry)

Delete the entire node modules dir and package-lock.json, and then running npm install helped me.