# Why can't React find this file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

React can't find this file that I'm trying to import.

I tried every different version of changing the filepath in the import I could, added/removed `.js` from all of the attempts, triple checked that there were no spelling errors/capitalization problems, and did an `npm update` just to try something different. I've hit a wall here.

The main errors I get are:

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/initrd.img'] {
> errno: -2,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'stat',
> path: '/initrd.img'
> }

> ./src/App.js
> Module not found: You attempted to import /components/number.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

I'm thinking it's a problem with how I'm trying to import/export things maybe? Here's the resources I've used to hack together what I have so far:

[mongoDB MERN tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial)

[geeksforgeeks tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mern-stack/)

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Numbers from './components/number.js'; 

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      buttonText: "button1"
    }

    this.changeWord = this.changeWord.bind(this);
  }

  changeWord() {
    if (this.state.buttonText === "button2") {
      this.setState({
        buttonText: "button1"
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        buttonText: "button2"
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <Numbers />
        <button className="test-button" onClick={this.changeWord}>{this.state.buttonText}</button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**number.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { response } from "express";

export default class Numbers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            numbers: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
        .get("http://localhost:3000/record/")
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                numbers: response.data
            });

            console.log(this.state.numbers);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Numbers</h3>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Number</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{this.numbers()}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the directory of your project, for example running the `tree /F` command on Windows? `./components/number.js`, which you are trying to import, seems to be outside of your `src` directory according to React.

Comment: @Capt171 `component/number.js` are inside of the `src` directory. I'll put up the directory when I can, but the path to `number.js` is `/home/schnondle/Desktop/testApp/test-app/src/components/number.js`. Edit: I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Well, I'm just confused as the error contradicts what you just said. @schnondle can you try using an absolute path (replacing `./component/number.js` with `/home/schnondle/Desktop/testApp/test-app/src/components/number.js`)

Comment: @Capt171 using `/home/schnondle/Desktop/testApp/test-app/src/components/number.js` provides the first error over again. I added the tree for you to look at

Comment: Try to create a code sandbox with this. If it doesn't work in the code sandbox, you'll get help, if it works there, you know you got some problems with your local environment... Like how you start the app or run React or something. Also, try to fix this other did with the image first.. maybe it's somehow related in some peculiar way. Is that a picture you're actually importing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64483296/potential-security-threat-detected-in-build-errors-in-a-fresh-create-react-app-i

Comment: @fast-reflexes anything in this directory besides the `component` directory and `number.js` came from `create-react-app test-app`. besides that I just added a button to the `app.js`

Comment: @fast-reflexes the code works in a sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I recently updated my machine using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, which for some reason seems to have broken the links to `/initrd.img` and `/initrd.img.old` in the root file path(`/`).

I ran `sudo update-grub`, which fixed that issue. Afterwards, I noticed that quickly before it (still) couldn't find `/initrd.img`, it would flash an error saying it couldn't find axios.

I ran `npm install axios`.

everything works now. Not sure which one fixed it, but hopefully this saves somebody else a 2 day headache!